# Firestore "where" query on timestamp field

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've trying to get all transactions of a user from last one year period but it's return nothing. Without date where clause it's working fine:

> Note! there is no error in console.

```
//Date one year before
let dateFrom = new Date();
dateFrom = new Date(dateFrom.setFullYear(dateFrom.getFullYear() - 1));

//Query not working
this.transCollection = this.afs.collection<Transaction>
('transactions', ref => ref.where('user_id', '==', this.user_id)
 .where('date', '>', dateFrom).orderBy('date', 'desc'));
);

//Query  working
this.transCollection = this.afs.collection<Transaction>
('transactions', ref => ref.where('user_id', '==', this.user_id)
 .orderBy('date', 'desc'));
);
```

[image]

Index:
[image]
Don't know what I've missing :(

Comment: Please add your database stucture and please responde with @.

Comment: You need to manually add an index over those two fields in order to make complex queries. Have you done that?

Comment: @SamiHult I've added index already

Comment: @AlexMamo Database structure added

Comment: Could you show a screen capture from the indices page, just in case?

Comment: You are using an index based on 4 properties but your query has only three, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo but it's working if i've removed second where.

Comment: @GovindSamrow If you are using a single `where`, there is no need for an index, right? Try to make a new index only on those properties and tell me if it works.

Comment: Are you sure the query isn't just returning 0 results?